# Why does changing (.|\n)* to (.| )* cause this huge drop in performance?

Tags: python, regex, performance, backtracking

I'm writing a regex for a warning I get on a Huawei CPE. The text I have to match is:

```
Warning: There are security risks in the configuration file. You are advised to save the configuration immediately. If you choose to save, the current configuration file will be unavailable after version downgrade.Are you sure to save now? [Y/N]:
```

And the regex I use to match it is the following:

```regex
Warning:(.|\n)*Are you sure to continue\?\s*\[Y/N\]:\s*$
```

It runs fine:

```sh
$ python3 -m timeit -s "import re;T=$text" "re.search(r'Warning:(.|\n)*Are you sure to continue\?\s*\[Y/N\]:\s*$', T)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.8 usec per loop
```

If I change `\n` to anything that contains a whitespace  then the regex suddenly becomes incredibly slow:

```
Warning:(.| )*Are you sure to continue\?\s*\[Y/N\]:\s*$
```

<sup>try with `\n|` or `\s` and it does the same</sup>

I don't bother with timeit simply because it has been running for minutes on my repl.

This is probably a problem with catastrophic backtracking, however I'd like to understand why it happens. In particular: why does whitespace matter?

Every whitespace  is already matched by `.` so it should never be used at all, and if `.` does not match then  does not match too, so I don't get why this would increase the number of backtracking steps.

Comment: They both are very poor patterns. Do not use them. *Every whitespace  is already matched by `.`* - but you did not prevent any backtracking into the subpattern, hence if subsequent subpatterns fail the engine comes back to `(.| )*` again and again. Actually, `(.| )` is the same as `.`, why use it at all? To match any char use `.` with `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: Please read about [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Whenever alternatives can match at the same location, the performance drops. `.` matches a space, but a dot does not match a newline by default. Add `re.S`, and you will see another drop in performance for `(.|\n)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why doesn't the engine optimize `.|xxx` into just `.` when `xxx =! \n`?